# Attempting to set related model fields via parent function call(s)

Tags: python, django

I am writing a Compact Disk Library editing routine.  The application allows you to enter a CD Artist Name, and CD Title and the total time of the CD.  User can then enter track information. While entering track information I want the application to display Current run time including this track, and time remaining based on length of the CD.  The models and functions are below

```
class Cd(models.Model):
  artist_name    = models.CharField(max_length=155)
  cd_title       = models.CharField(max_length=155)
  cd_total_time           = models.TimeField(default="00:00:00")
  cd_total_time_delta     = models.DurationField(default=timedelta)
  cd_run_time         = models.TimeField(default="00:00:00",blank=True)
  cd_run_time_delta   = models.DurationField(default=timedelta)
  cd_remaining_time       = models.TimeField(default="00:00:00",blank=True)
  cd_remaining_time_delta = models.DurationField(default=timedelta)

  def convert_to_delta(self,time_in):
    hold_time = time_in.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    t = datetime.strptime(hold_time,"%H:%M:%S")
    return(timedelta(hours=t.hour, minutes=t.minute, seconds=t.second))

  def calculate_time(self):
    cd_total_time_delta = self.convert_to_delta(self.cd_total_time)
    cd_total_run_time_delta = timedelta(minutes=0)
    for track in self.cd_tracks.all():
      cd_total_run_time_delta += track.trk_length_time_delta
      track.trk_run_time_delta += cd_total_run_time_delta
      track.trk_run_time = f"{track.trk_run_time_delta}"
      track.trk_remaining_time_delta = cd_total_time_delta - cd_total_run_time_delta
      track.trk_remaining_time = f"{track.trk_remaining_time_delta}"

    self.cd_run_time_delta = cd_total_run_time_delta
    self.cd_run_time = f"{self.cd_run_time_delta}"
    self.cd_remaining_time_delta = self.cd_total_time_delta - cd_total_run_time_delta
    self.cd_remaining_time = f"{abs(self.cd_remaining_time_delta)}"

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.calculate_time()
    super().save(*args,**kwargs)

  def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.artist_name} : {self.cd_title}"

class Track(models.Model):
  cd_id = models.ForeignKey(Cd, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    related_name='cd_tracks',
  )
  track_title   = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  track_number  = models.IntegerField()
  trk_length_time     = models.TimeField(null=True,default=None, blank=True)
  trk_length_time_delta = models.DurationField(default=timedelta)
  trk_run_time         = models.TimeField(default="00:00:00",blank=True)
  trk_run_time_delta   = models.DurationField(default=timedelta)
  trk_remaining_time       = models.TimeField(default="00:00:00",blank=True)
  trk_remaining_time_delta = models.DurationField(default=timedelta)

  def calculate_track_delta(self):
      self.trk_length_time_delta = self.cd_id.convert_to_delta(self.trk_length_time)

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
      self.calculate_track_delta()
      super().save(*args,**kwargs)
      self.cd_id.save()

  def __str__(self):
      return f"{self.track_title}"
```

When I attempt to update a track by entering in the track length time, name etc. and pressing submit, it should calculate all of the track data for each track. It DOES calculate the CD Total run time and remaining time, but the track values do not get updated.  I am thinking my code isn't actually referencing the actual object correctly? Or the parent is not saving the child data...(how would I write that?).

Thanks
This is what the actual Parent Update Form looks like:
[image: Update CD Form]

The Run Time I entered manually via admin, to see if that helped (it didn't). The time remaining should be the total time minus run time (run time increases of course for each track).

below is the template itself:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %} Update CD {% endblock title %}
{% block content %}
<h1>CD Update </h1>

{% if submitted %}
  <p>
    Your CD information  was submitted successfully. Thank You.
  </p>

{% else %}
  <form action="" method="post" novalidate>
  <table>
    {{ form.as_table }}
    {% if not cd.cd_tracks.all %}
      No Tracks Added
    {% else %}
      <TABLE BORDER="0" TABLE_LAYOUT="fixed" WIDTH="100%">
      <TR BGCOLOR="#B0B0FF">
        <TD></TD>
        <TD ALIGN="Center">&nbsp;Track #</TD>
        <TD ALIGN="Center"> Cut Title</TD>
        <TD ALIGN="Center">Track Length</TD>
        <TD ALIGN="Center" BGCOLOR="#CC99CC">Run Time</TD>
        <TD ALIGN="Center" BGCOLOR="#CC99CC">Time Remaining</TD>
      </TR>
      {% for tracks in cd.cd_tracks.all %}
          <TR>
            <TD ALIGN="Center" rowspan="1" height="33" width="33">
              <!--    Turning Off anchor No mix view yet
              <A href=" url 'cd_mixed_view' cd.pk tracks.pk ">
              -->
              <IMG SRC="{% static 'images/edit.gif' %}">
              </A>
            </TD>
            <TD ALIGN="Left" VALIGN="Top" WIDTH="10">&nbsp;{{ tracks.track_number }}</TD>
            <TD ALIGN="Left" VALIGN="Top">&nbsp;{{ tracks.track_title }}</TD>
            <TD ALIGN="Left" VALIGN="Top">{{ tracks.trk_length_time|time:"H:i:s" }}</TD>
            <TD ALIGN="Left" VALIGN="Top">{{ tracks.trk_run_time|time:"H:i:s" }}</TD>
            {% if tracks.trk_remaining_time_delta < "00:00:00" %}
              <TD BGCOLOR="#8DF1BF" ALIGN="Left">&nbsp;(-{{ tracks.trk_remaining_time|time:"H:i:s" }})</TD>
            {% else %}
              <TD BGCOLOR="#8DF1BF" ALIGN="Left">&nbsp;{{ tracks.trk_remaining_time|time:"H:i:s" }}</TD>
            {% endif %}
          </TR>
        {% endfor %}
      </TABLE>
    {% endif %}
    <tr>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  {% csrf_token %}
  </form>
{% endif %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code was close. The most major problem was I was not saving the child model in the parent correctly (or at all really).
Uddate model is :

```
class Cd(models.Model):
  artist_name    = models.CharField(max_length=155)
  cd_title       = models.CharField(max_length=155)
  cd_total_time           = models.TimeField(default="00:00:00")
  cd_total_time_delta     = models.DurationField(default=timedelta)
  cd_run_time         = models.TimeField(default="00:00:00",blank=True)
  cd_run_time_delta   = models.DurationField(default=timedelta)
  cd_remaining_time       = models.TimeField(default="00:00:00",blank=True)
  cd_remaining_time_delta = models.DurationField(default=timedelta)

  def convert_to_delta(self,time_in):
    hold_time = time_in.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    t = datetime.strptime(hold_time,"%H:%M:%S")
    return(timedelta(hours=t.hour, minutes=t.minute, seconds=t.second))

  def calculate_time(self):
    cd_total_time_delta = self.convert_to_delta(self.cd_total_time)
    cd_total_run_time_delta = timedelta(minutes=0)
    for track in self.cd_tracks.all():
      cd_total_run_time_delta += track.trk_length_time_delta
      track.trk_run_time_delta = cd_total_run_time_delta
      track.trk_run_time = f"{track.trk_run_time_delta}"
      track.trk_remaining_time_delta = cd_total_time_delta - cd_total_run_time_delta
      track.trk_remaining_time = f"{abs(track.trk_remaining_time_delta)}"
      super(Track,track).save()

    self.cd_run_time_delta = cd_total_run_time_delta
    self.cd_run_time = f"{self.cd_run_time_delta}"
    self.cd_remaining_time_delta = self.cd_total_time_delta - cd_total_run_time_delta
    self.cd_remaining_time = f"{abs(self.cd_remaining_time_delta)}"

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.calculate_time()
    super().save(*args,**kwargs)
```